# The code in my textbox validating event is causing error 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'

Tags: c#, ms-access

Visual C# 2008 Express.  Access 2010 database.  When I use the following code I receive an error 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression', but if I take out the code for the txt85x11bw_Validating event it works just fine.  I'm trying to understand how there is a date type mismatch.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace GISReciepts
{
public partial class GISReceipts : Form
{
    public GISReceipts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cmdExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1(Name1, Date1, CollectedBy, 85x11BW) VALUES(@Name, @Date, @CollectedBy, @85x11BW)";

        //OleDbConnection is a class that represents an open connection to a data source
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Temp\\GISTest.accdb");
        //OleDbCommand is a class that represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a data source.(takes care of passing queries to the database.
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", maskedTextBoxDate.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectedBy", txtCollectedBy.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", txt85x11bw.Text);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
           // MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");  //this is displaying even on errors & when no data is added to table
        }

    }

    private void GISReceipts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBoxDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        txt85x11bw.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(txt85x11bw_Validating);       
    }


    private void GISReceipts_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime value;
        //DateTime.TryParse converts the srting representation of a date to its DateTime equivalent & returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succedded.
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(maskedTextBoxDate.Text, out value))
        {
            maskedTextBoxDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        }

    }

    private void txt85x11bw_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt85x11bw.Text))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            //initialize the variable numberEntered of type int
            int numberEntered;

            //int=integer TryParse=method that converts strings into integer (value, out result)
            if (int.TryParse(txt85x11bw.Text, out numberEntered))
            {
                //if number is less than 1 or more than 1,000
                if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 1000)
                    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a valid number");
                txt85x11bw.Clear();

            }
            //if conversion failed
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number");
                txt85x11bw.Clear();

            }
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: To get the messagebox that says "Entry Added" to stop showing even when an error occurs, move the MessageBox.Show() function out of the finally clause, and to the end of the try statement (after myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery), because your finally statement will always execute, if there is an error, or if it succeeds.

Comment: thanks. that was another issue that I was goign to work on later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line adds a parameter with a datatype text, instead, I assume, that in your database the column 85x11BW is of numeric type (an int looking at your validating code)

```
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", txt85x11bw.Text);
```

try to change the line in this way

```
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", Convert.ToInt32(txt85x11bw.Text));
```

in this way you force the AddWithValue method to add a parameter with its `DbType` property set to `Int32`. You could have the same problem for the parameter `@Date`, if the relative datatable column is of `DateTime` type.

**EDIT** If the txt85x11BW is empty you need to decide which default value you accept for that column in the datatable. If you accept a NULL you could write something like this

```
        int numberEntered = 0;
        int.TryParse(txt85x11bw.Text, out numberEntered);
        if (numberEntered >= 1 && numberEntered <= 1000)
             myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", numberEntered);
        else
             myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", DBNull.Value);
```

**EDIT 2**   In the validating event the code clears the content of the maskedit also if the value is correct. You need braces after the condition

```
if (int.TryParse(txt85x11bw.Text, out numberEntered))
{
    //if number is less than 1 or more than 1,000
    if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 1000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a valid number");
        txt85x11bw.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: The database column for this is numeric, but when I try your solution that line becomes highlighted with 'FormatException was unhandled.  input string was not in a coorect format'.

Comment: Perhaps this is caused by a blank value in txt85x11bw. Do you accept a null in the datatable for this column?

Comment: I accept null values, but I've been testing it using a number and I still get an data type error.  I've checked my type format in my table in access and it is of the integer type.

Comment: I guess the next thing I'll try is restricting the input to only numbers in a KeyPress event.

Comment: heve you tried the update? Sorry but I'm busy today and so I don't check constantly.

Comment: myCommand does not exist in the current context.  You have an extra ) on the last two lines.

Comment: I've searched for other options to do this for hours and I'm still stuck.  So what is the best way to handle a null value for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I changed `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", Convert.ToInt32(txt85x11bw.Text));` to `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@85x11BW", String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt85x11bw.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txt85x11bw.Text);` I don't receive any errors, but nothign is saved to the table in my database.

Comment: I have just found a possible cause of your distress. In the validating event you clear the maskedit also if the value is correct. See my update

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, but I don't understand the logic behind why it solved it.  My date textbox is masked, but not the txt85x11bw in question.